# Parsing getopts in bash

Tags: bash, function, getopts

I've got a bash function that I'm trying to use getopts with and am having some trouble.

The function is designed to be called by itself (`getch`), with an optional `-s` flag (`getch -s`), or with an optional string argument afterward (so `getch master` and `getch -s master` are both valid).

The snippet below is where my problem lies - it isn't the entire function, but it's what I'm focusing on:

```
getch()
{
  if [ "$#" -gt 2 ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [-s] [branch-name]" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  while getopts "s" opt; do
    echo $opt # This line is here to test how many times we go through the loop
    case $opt in
      s) 
        squash=true
        shift
        ;;
      *) 
        ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

The `getch -s master` case is where the strangeness happens.  The above should spit out `s` once, but instead, I get this:

```
[user@host:git-repositories/temp]$ getch -s master
s
s
[user@host:git-repositories/temp]$
```

Why is it parsing the `-s` opt twice?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing this problem.  I copied your code into a file, and ran it with -s master, -s -s -s, and any other silly things, and can't get more than 1 s to print.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it either. It works fine for me. Change your `echo $opt` to `echo "In getopts: $opt"` to make it distinct in case something else is echoing it.

Comment: Put `OPTIND=1` before the getops loop. `$OPTIND` is the position in the parameters list that is to be parsed next by getopts (When you finish the while loop, you should do a `shift $((OPTIND-1))` to "shift away" those parsed parameters). If you omit to re-set OPTIND to 1, the next time you do a getopts in the current shell (ex: another function), you will parse starting at $OPTIND-th parameter, usually empty, making getops return false and the "while" exits straight away, without parsing the parameters.

Comment: and don't `shift` inside the getops loop. Instead, after `done`, put a `shift $((OPTIND -1))` so it shifts out all the parameters that getopts parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem either, on an Ubuntu 10.4 box running Bash 4, or my MacOSX box running Bash 3.2.17.

Your shell environment might be tainted by earlier debugging efforts.

Have you tried to start with a new terminal window? Or start a new shell with 'exec bash' and try the function again.

```
stefanl@ubuntu:~ $ getch()
> {
>   if [ "$#" -gt 2 ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
>     echo "Usage: $0 [-s] [branch-name]" >&2
>     return 1
>   fi
> 
>   while getopts "s" opt; do
>     echo $opt # This line is here to test how many times we go through the loop
>     case $opt in
>       s) 
>         squash=true
>         shift
>         ;;
>       *) 
>         ;;
>     esac
>   done
> }
stefanl@ubuntu:~ $ getch -s master
s
```

Comment: I tried doing a new subshell, as you suggested, and it worked.  Must have done something to my environment beforehand... Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: This happens from time to time. It's easy to become stuck debugging a script, and forget that your environment can become corrupt.

Comment: (deleting the comments I wrongly put in this answer instead of in the asker's post)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without getopts:

http://bsdpants.blogspot.com/2007/02/option-ize-your-shell-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the options outside of a function you've written.  I toyed around with this a little bit more this afternoon.  I had a hard time having it work properly when parsing the options in a function as opposed to just in the main body of the script.

Otherwise, I don't really know what to tell you.